# Why is $E[XY, X = i] = iE[Y, X = i]$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value, independence

So i am working on a problem in probability theory and i came across the following equation

$$E[XY\mid \mathcal{F}]  = \sum_{i \in [6]}E[XY\mid X = i]1_{\{X=i\}} = \sum_{i \in [6]}\frac{E[XY, X = i]}{P[X=i]}1_{\{X=i\}} = \sum_{i \in [6]}\frac{iE[Y, X = i]}{P[X=i]}1_{\{X=i\}} = \sum_{i \in [6]}\frac{iE[Y]P[X = i]}{P[X=i]}1_{\{X=i\}}$$

For context: $[6]$ describes the set $\{1,...,6\}$ and $X,Y$ are the projections $X,Y: [6]^2 \to [6]$ and $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(X)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the projection $X$.

Unfortunately, I dont know why the 3rd "=" and the last "=" hold. Can someone help me understanding these 2 equations?

Comment: are you sure $1_{X=i}$ is part of the last formula?

Comment: yes, this is exactly as it is in my script.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are independent? What is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E[XY\mid \mathcal{F}]  = \sum_{i \in [6]}E[XY\mid X = i]1_{\{X=i\}} \overset{(1)}{=}
 \sum_{i \in [6]}iE[Y\mid X = i]1_{\{X=i\}}
$$
$$\overset{(2)}{=}\sum_{i \in [6]}i\frac{E(Y1_{\{X=i \}})}{P(X=i)}1_{\{X=i\}}$$

$$\overset{(3)}{=}\sum_{i \in [6]}i\frac{E(Y) E(1_{\{X=i \}})}{P(X=i)}1_{\{X=i\}}$$

$$=\sum_{i \in [6]}i\frac{E(Y) P(X=i )}{P(X=i)}1_{\{X=i\}}$$
$$=E(Y) \sum_{i \in [6]} i 1_{\{X=i\}}\overset{(4)}{=}E(Y)X$$

(1) Since $E(f(X)Y\mid X)=f(X)E(Y\mid X)$

(2) $E(Y|A)=\frac{E(Y1_A)}{P(A)}$

(3) $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

(4) $X$ is a simple function and $X=\sum_{i \in [6]} i 1_{\{X=i\}}$

Comment: thank you Masoud for showing me each equation, i really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @zest, You are welcome.

Comment: one remaining question is, why does (1) hold? I.e. where does $E(f(X)Y\mid X) = f(X)E(Y\mid X)$ follow from? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: It is a property of conditional expectation. $E(f(X)Y|X=t)=E(f(t)Y|X=t)=f(t)E(Y|X=t)$. Since if you know the value of $X$, you know the exact value of $f(X)$

Comment: for more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation the line "Pulling out known factors:"

Comment: beautiful, thank you so much Masoud.

Comment: @Zest , You are welcome. Feel free to ask!